# How does a bass with tilted frets work?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar, fretboard

I have seen some basses that have frets that are tilted. Here is an example:

[image]

How is a fretboard like this functional? Is there any difference between this fretboard and a normal one?

Comment: I've never seen that before. That's bizarre.

Comment: The photo improves the question, so I have copied it over to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a standard bass (or guitar), the nut and bridge are basically parallel, and perpendicular to the strings. The saddles will never be an exact straight line, so they are usually (on electrics) made to be adjustable. On this, the top string (G) is 3-4 frets shorter than the bottom B. So each string would be out of tune (intonation) if the frets were parallel.

The twelfth fret ought to be the perpendicular one, with everything else fanning away from it, both sides.Although it doesn't look exactly so from the pic.

It will work, but why you'd need one, I don't know. The string set won't be standard, as the shorter G and longer B will mess up the tension.Interesting though.What make ?